# How to use sitemap.xml to create a static mirror of a CMS

Tags: curl, wget, sitemap

Is there a tool to create a static mirror of a content management system (CMS) that provides a sitemap.xml file?

Ideally, I would point a tool like wget or curl to a sitemap.xml file and have it automatically sync the static directories using the provided URL's and timestamps. New content would be pulled down, removed content would be deleted.

Comment: Which CMS are you using?